# SQL Delivery Rate calculation

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to calculate the delivery rate using SQL

`total sent minus bounces/total sent * 100`

I have tried hardcoding this "`Select 90/100*100`" so this should be `90%` delivery rate. when checking the data extension it's showing zero.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make life alot simpler, I would respect the rules of Alegbra and put things in brackets.

```
Select 90/100*100
```

is `90 / (100*100)`

will give you 0.0009 (which is why it looked like 0 as your field probably didnt have enough decimal places.

```
SELECT 90.0/100.0*100.0 will also give you 0.0009
```

To get 90%,

```
SELECT (90.0/100.0)*100.0
```

**References:**

- [Mathematical Operations](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html)

Comment: Can you help with another question I have? I'm trying to convert a number to a decimal as it keeps failing to run here's the code not sure where I'm going wrong SELECT 
Total_Staging,
TOTAL_Pre_Sent,
Total_Deployed,
Total_Opens,
Total_Opens_Unique,
Total_Clicks,
jobID,
EmailName,
Total_Bounced,
delivered,
Convert(decimal(4,1), Delivered) as delivered_updated,
Convert(decimal(4,1), Total_Deployed) as Total_Deployed_updated,
Convert(decimal(4,1), Total_Bounced) as Total_Bounced_updated
FROM PH_Daily_Checks

Comment: post it as another question and I will try. If not it makes it easier for someone else to pick up

Comment: also post the error message

Answer (score 0):

Using whole numbers in SQL results in "integer" math. In integer math, the fraction is discarded, such that 90/100 is equal to 0 (90/100 is 0.9, then dropping the decimal value results in 0). Multiply before you divide, or use an explicit decimal value.

---

```
SELECT 100*90/100
```

---

```
SELECT 90.0/100.0*100.0
```

Comment: I have just tried this. however, I'm not sure why it's doing the below   30.0*33.0/100.0 as Delivery_rate = this gives me 9.9 and it should be 90.9
    90.0*100.0/100.0 as Delivery_rate_PC I have just tried this one and it gives me 90.0 which is correct. what I am trying to do is calculate the delivery rate dynamically.